# PHP codeigniter variable not being passed to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function create()
{
    $data['headline'] =" ";
    $this->load->module('site_security');
    $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();

    $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3); 

    if(!is_numeric($update_id))
    {
        $data['headline'] = "Add New Product";
        //$data['headline'] = print_r($update_id)."if";
    }

    else
    {
        $data['headine'] = "Update Product Details";
        //$data['headline'] = print_r($update_id)."else";
    }

    $data['view_module'] = "store_products"; //passing module name 
    $data['view_file'] = "create";  //passing method name
    $this->load->module('templates'); // loads the template module
    $this->templates->admin($data); //calls the template controller method admin which loads the admin view

}
```

I am passing the headline text through to change heading in a view depending on the content of the third 3rd segment in the url. The first if statement sets the heading perfectly but it wont go into the else statement and was giving me errors because $headline was undefined in the view. Oddly enough if i use the commented print_r statements everything works perfect it will display it in the view.

Im thinking it has to be the line $data['headine'] = "Update Product Details"; in the else but i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement,

```
 else
 {
     $data['headine'] = "Update Product Details";
 }
```

You have a typo here. change `headine` to `headline`.